# How to fix this: Object are not valid as a React Child

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

[The Error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM9Hn.png)

i need help how to fix this problem, sorry iam newbie in react native, I've been stuck for hours, Hope anyone can help to fix this..

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: it seems like you using object instead of array in your render. please add your code for reference.

Comment: this is my code here  sir => https://pastebin.com/2H0mfkPp

Comment: do you want to render value of `page` key from PAGES variable ?

Comment: in this case i want to throw a data array containing components, StepOne, StepTwo and StepThree so that they can be displayed in the ViewPager component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call this

```
{PAGES.map((page) => this.renderViewPagerPage(page))}
```

you are passing complete object  `{"id":1,"page":<StepOne></StepOne>}` inside `Text` component, you just need to pass the text you want to render rather than whole object.

replace your below code

```
renderViewPagerPage = (data) => {
    return(<View style={styles.page}>
      <Text>{data}</Text>
    </View>)
  }
```

with

```
 renderViewPagerPage = (data) => {
        return(<View style={styles.page}>
          <Text>{data.page}</Text>
        </View>)
      }
```